# How to access the date_histogram key field in the child aggregation in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I want to apply some filters on the bucket response generated by the `date_histogram`, that filter is dependent on the key of the `date_histogram` output buckets.

Suppose I have following data in

```
{
   "entryTime":"",
   "soldTime:""
}
```

the elastic query is something like this

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "date": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "entryTime",
        "interval": "month",
        "keyed": true
      },
      "aggs": {
        "filter_try": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "range": {
                    "entryTime": {
                      "lte": 1588840533000
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "bool": {
                    "should": [
                      {
                        "bool": {
                          "must": [
                            {
                              "exists": {
                                "field": "soldTime"
                              }
                            },
                            {
                              "range": {
                                "soldTime": {
                                  "gt": 1588840533000
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "bool": {
                          "must_not": [
                            {
                              "exists": {
                                "field": "soldTime"
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

so here in that bool query, I want to use the date generated for the specific bucket by `date_histogram` aggregation in both the range clauses instead of the hardcoded epoch time.

Even if we can access using script then also it's fine.

for further clarification, this is the boolean query and in the query want to replace this `"DATE"` with the `date_histogram` bucket key.

```
# (entryTime < DATE) 
# AND 
# (
#    (soldTime != null AND soldTime > DATE) 
#          OR 
#      (soldTime == NULL)
#  )
```

Consider below 10 Document I have:

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "vi_test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "deaerId" : "4",
          "entryTime" : "1577869200000",
          "soldTime" : "1578646800000"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "vi_test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "deaerId" : "4",
          "entryTime" : "1578214800000"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "vi_test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "deaerId" : "4",
          "entryTime" : "1578560400000",
          "soldTime" : "1579942800000"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "vi_test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "4",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "deaerId" : "4",
          "entryTime" : "1579683600000",
          "soldTime" : "1581325200000"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "vi_test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "5",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "deaerId" : "4",
          "entryTime" : "1580893200000"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "vi_test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "6",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "deaerId" : "4",
          "entryTime" : "1582189200000",
          "soldTime" : "1582362000000"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "vi_test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "7",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "deaerId" : "4",
          "entryTime" : "1582621200000",
          "soldTime" : "1584349200000"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "vi_test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "8",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "deaerId" : "4",
          "entryTime" : "1583053200000",
          "soldTime" : "1583830800000"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "vi_test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "9",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "deaerId" : "4",
          "entryTime" : "1584262800000"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "vi_test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "10",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "deaerId" : "4",
          "entryTime" : "1585472400000"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Now the end of January 2020 in epoch is -> `1580515199000`

So if I apply on the above-mentioned bool query,

Will get the output as the

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "vi_test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "4",
        "_score" : 3.0,
        "_source" : {
          "deaerId" : "4",
          "entryTime" : "1579683600000",
          "soldTime" : "1581325200000"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "vi_test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "deaerId" : "4",
          "entryTime" : "1578214800000"
        }
      }
    ]
```

As document with ID 4 satisfy `(soldTime != null AND soldTime > DATE)` and document with ID 2 satisfy `(soldTime == null)` condition from OR part.

Now for the same bool request If I use the date of end February 2020 -> `1583020799000`, will get the hits as follows

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "vi_test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "7",
        "_score" : 3.0,
        "_source" : {
          "deaerId" : "4",
          "entryTime" : "1582621200000",
          "soldTime" : "1584349200000"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "vi_test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "deaerId" : "4",
          "entryTime" : "1578214800000"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "vi_test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "5",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "deaerId" : "4",
          "entryTime" : "1580893200000"
        }
      }
    ]
```

- ID 7: Entry in Feb, but sold in March so is in stock for Feb-2020
- ID 2: Entry in Jan, not sold yet means in the stock
- ID 5: Entry in Feb, not sold yet means in the stock

Now the same data required for each end of the month of a whole year to plot the trend.

Thank you

Comment: Date histogram will create  monthly bucket based on entry time i.e documets will be grouped based on month of entry time. If your query you have put a condition entry time <start of month. It will not return anything as that bucket only contain documnets which fall in that month. can you elaborate your requirement further to better understand it

Comment: Yes @jaspreetchahal, It will work for that time also, the requirement is to get the documents which fulfill the condition at the end of each month. Documents contain data for the vehicle which came at some time --> `entryTime` and get sold after some time --> `soldTime`. using these values want to get the inventory trend using the histogram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way using normal queries as parent aggregation key is not available in sub aggregation. I have written a script for this which selects documents where soldTime is either null or doesnot fall in same month as entryTime

**Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "script": {
      "script": """
         ZonedDateTime entry;
         ZonedDateTime sold;
         if(doc['entryTime'].size()>0)
         {
           entry= doc['entryTime'].value;
         }
         if(doc['soldTime'].size()>0) 
         {
           sold = doc['soldTime'].value;
         }
         if(sold==null || ( entry.getMonthValue()!==sold.getMonthValue()|| entry.getYear()!==sold.getYear()))
         {
           return true;
         }
         else false;
"""
    }
  },
  "size": 10,
  "aggs": {
    "monthly_trend": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "entryTime",
        "interval": "month"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "docs": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index22",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "55Kv83EB8a54AbXfngYU",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "deaerId" : "4",
          "entryTime" : "1578214800000"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "monthly_trend" : {
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key" : 1577836800000,
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "docs" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 1,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : 1.0,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "index22",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "55Kv83EB8a54AbXfngYU",
                  "_score" : 1.0,
                  "_source" : {
                    "deaerId" : "4",
                    "entryTime" : "1578214800000"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you @jaspreetchahal for your response, I have edited the question with more details and example. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you @jaspreetchahal, it really helped!!. One more addition I have done as part of the date_histogram child aggregation added the cummulative_sum on the count of documents and it worked well!

Comment: @ViralShah Glad could be of help